# Failed to convert NVARCHAR to INT, but I'm not trying to

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'L NOVAK ENTERPRISES, INC' to data type int.

I've been wrestling with this query for quite a while and just can't figure out in what place that the conversion is being attempted. Using SQL Server 2017.

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DateTime
DECLARE @MfgGroupCode AS Varchar(20)

SET @StartDate='2/27/2020'
SET @MfgGroupCode = 'VOLVO_NLA'

SELECT DISTCINT
    CT.No_ AS [Contact Number],
    CT.Name AS [Contact Name],
    UAL.Time AS [Search Date],
    UAL.Param1 AS [Search Part],
    CT.[E-Mail] AS [Contact Email],
    CT.[Phone No_] AS [Contact Phone],
    CT.[Company Name] AS [Search By Customer],
    (SELECT C.Name 
     FROM dbo.[Customer] C 
     WHERE C.No_ = SL.[Sell-to Customer No_] 
       AND C.Name <> '') AS [Sold To Customer],
    SL.[Posting Date] AS [Invoice Date],
    SL.[Document No_] AS [Invoice],
    SL.Quantity AS [Quantity],
    SL.[Unit Price] AS [Unit Price],
    SL.Amount AS [Amount],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, UAL.Time, SL.[Posting Date]) AS [Interval]
FROM
    dbo.[User Action Log] UAL
JOIN
    dbo.[User Action Types] UAT ON UAL.[User Action ID] = UAT.ID
JOIN 
    dbo.[Item] I ON UAL.Param1 = I.[OEM Part Number]
JOIN 
    dbo.[Contact] CT ON UAL.[Contact No_] = CT.No_
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.[Sales Invoice Line] SL ON UAL.Param1 = SL.[OEM Part Number] 
                                AND SL.[Posting Date] >= @StartDate
WHERE
    UAT.Name IN ('SinglePartSearch', 'MultiPartSearch')
    AND UAL.[MFG Group Code] = @MfgGroupCode
    AND UAL.Time >= @StartDate
    AND UAL.Param3 > 0
    -- AND DATEDIFF(DAY, UAL.Time, SL.[Posting Date]) < 0             -- Uncomment to see Current Searches with Past Orders
    -- AND DATEDIFF(DAY, UAL.Time, SL.[Posting Date]) > -1            -- Uncomment to see Searches resulting in Future Order
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, UAL.Time, SL.[Posting Date]) IS NULL   -- Uncomment to See Searches with no Order
ORDER BY
    Interval DESC
```

Comment: have you enabled line numbers in preferences?  My guess is that in one of the rows of your data, there is the company name in the wrong column

Comment: Could be in any of your joins. Where does the value `L NOVAK ENTERPRISES, INC` exist?

Comment: Yes, to line numbers. The 'L NOVAK ENTERPRISES, INC' exists in the CT.Company Name, C.Name, and CT.Name Fields.

Comment: Seems you're comparing an `int` to a `varchar` somewhere; without DDL and sample data though, we don't really know *where* this would be.

Comment: @JoshuaJohnston just because the query can't return those rows doesn't mean the comparison won't happen in the `WHERE`.

Comment: That was the clarity I needed @Larnu - when I comment that line out, it returns results. When I run this query `SELECT * FROM
[Lippert].[dbo].[$User Action Log]
WHERE
[Param3] LIKE '%NOVAK%' PARAM3` on it's own, there is in fact a row that will return the "L NOVAK" value for param3.

Comment: You can try systematically commenting out parts of the where clause that may cause the issue to see if then runs ok. That can eliminate some possible areas

Comment: The order that SQL Server performs the `WHERE` may not be the order the clauses are in your query. SQL Server will check the indexes, statistics, etc, and make an "informed" decision on what is the best method. If it finds it's quicker/more efficient to perform the `WHERE` in a different order to that you have written it in, it will do. I've even have queries fail that have worked for years, as due to the statistics being updated it caused an error like this, as something that was previously filtered earlier in the plan "bubbled up" to be processed earlier in it. Took *ages* to figure that out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of your help and questioning, I was able to identify that the culprit is `UAL.Param3`.
The User Action Log table stores a variety of different "Actions" and the parameters that are affiliated with each type of action (param1, param2, param3). For one action "RequestForAccess", the "L NOVAK" value is perfectly acceptable. For this query, we're looking at the "SinglePartSearch" and "MultiPartSearch" actions, which will only contain numeric values in `UAL.Param3`

I replaced this line (`AND UAL.Param3 > 0`) with (`AND ISNUMERIC(UAL.Param3) = 1 AND UAL.Param3 <> 0`) in the Where clause and it is now returning the results I hoped for.

Let me know if there is a more correct way of doing this and thank you to all who contributed!